# Parsing and displaying large json files in SageMaker

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-sagemaker, jupyter-lab

I have gzipped json files in S3 and I'm trying to show them in a `SageMaker Studio Notebook` like so:

```py
import boto3
import gzip


s3_object = s3.Object("bucket", "path")
with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=s3_object.get()["Body"]) as gzip_file:
    print("reading s3 object through gzip stream")
    raw_json = gzip_file.read()
    print("done reading s3 object, about to flush")
    gzip_file.flush()
    print("done flushing")

print("about to print")
print(raw_json.decode("utf-8"))
print("done printing")
```

My constraint is that it has to be done in memory, I've resorted to running on a `ml.m5.2xlarge` instance which should be more than enough.

I know of `IPython.display.JSON`, `pandas.read_json` and `json.load()/json.loads()`, I'm treating the content as a plain string to keep the question simple.

The (unexpected) output of the above code is:

```
reading s3 object through gzip stream
done reading s3 object, about to flush
done flushing
about to display
```

At this point the kernel status is 'Busy' and it can remain like that for a few good minutes until finally it seems to just kind of 'give up' with no output.

If I run the exact same code in a notebook running on my laptop it works just fine, quickly showing the json content.

What am I missing? Is there a better way to do this?

My endgame is to sometimes present data in a pandas `DataFrame` and sometimes show it as an `IPython.display.JSON` for conveniently viewing content

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with Studio.How big is your json file?
I would recommend you convert it to pandas DF to view it on the console.

Comment: I tried both downloading in the same manner and instantiating a DF out of the content and `read_json` with an `s3://` path direct - it still doesn't render.
my json files are quite big, can be anywhere between 10-150 MB